# horizontal scrollview for different screen sizes ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Hi I need some help ScrollViews. I want to have a horizontal scrollview take up the bottom 25% of a screen and stay at 25% across all iPhone screen sizes. I am just not sure how to code it in Swift. I know that I should not give it a fixed width and height like I have. Does anyone know how I can do this or where I can look for help?  My main problem is that when I switch between devices it does not stay the same height and width. I am using a stackview.

```
import UIKit

class paintedLadiesVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let WIDTH: CGFloat = 414
    let HEIGTH: CGFloat = 212

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        for var x = 1; x <= 5; x++ {
            let img = UIImage(named: "\(x)")
            let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)

            scrollView.addSubview(imgView)

            imgView.frame = CGRectMake(-WIDTH + (WIDTH * CGFloat(x)), 1, WIDTH, HEIGTH)

        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(WIDTH * 5, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use an aspect ratio constraint between the height of your scrollview and the height of the superview

Answer (score 0):

Base your sizes on the device using 'UIDevice.currentDevice().width ' 'UIDevice.currentDevice().height'